# Integral cohomology on compact irreducible holomorphic symplectic manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, hyperkaehler

In particular, I'm attempting to understand the integral cohomology on K3^[4], a Hilbert scheme on the projective K3 surface, and whether or not this compact Kaehler manifold admits a Kaehler form that represents an integral class. Unlike on K3 itself, here we have b_{2}=23, so the solution to this question isn't merely a matter of rescaling to achieve an integral Kaehler form. Would any of the experts here have any glimmerings of an approach to take here, or a useful paper/text to recommend? After plenty of browsing, I have found information about the integral cohomology on this manifold, but nothing addressing the feasibility of selecting a Kaehler form that represents an integral class.

Comment: I don't get it. If you start from a projective K3, its Hilbert scheme is projective. What is the problem? How the value of $b_2$ being 22 or 23 can be relevant?

Comment: Ah, by Kodaira Embedding Theorem? I am a novice in algebraic geometry, and I appreciate you pointing out an important principle like this.